# Why is my code not able to print Prime Numbers within the given range?

Tags: c

I'm trying to print the Prime numbers between a given range but I get blank output. Where have I gone wrong? Is it a logic mistake or implementation mistake?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int isPrime(int i)
{
    int j;
    for(j=2; j<=i; j++)
    {
        if(i%j==0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
int main()
{
    int cases, n1, n2, i;
    scanf("%d", &cases);
    while(cases>0)
    {
        scanf("%d%d", &n1, &n2);
        for(i=n1; i<=n2; i++)
        {
            if(isPrime(i))
            {
                printf("%d\t", i);
            }
        }
        cases--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at the condition in your for-loop in `isPrime`

Comment: It is a logic mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must stop the loop in `isPrime` before `i` because all non zero numbers are divisible by themselves:

```
int isPrime(int i) {
    int j;
    for (j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Note that you should also return `0` for numbers below `2`.  Furthermore, you can improve performance dramatically by stopping at the square root of `i` and by testing only odd numbers above `2`.

```
int isPrime(int i) {
    if (i <= 2) {
        return i == 2;
    }
    for (int j = 3; j * j <= i; j += 2) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`i%i==0` will be always true unless `i` is zero, so `isPrime` will return `0` for whatever `i` which is 2 or greater.

You can use `j<i` instead of `j<=i`, for example.

Another point is that your `isPrime` will mistakenly judge all integers that is 1 or less as primes, so you should check for them before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from being sub-optimal, your code goes all the way to `i` when trying to find the divisor. This means that all checks will eventually succeed when `i == j`, so `i%j` is zero.

A better stopping condition for the loop is

```
for( j=2 ; j*j <= i ; j++)
```

In other words, stop upon passing the square root of `i`. This is valid, because if you have not found proper divisors smaller than the square root, then it is guaranteed that there are also no divisors larger than the square root.

If you know the upper limit for `n2`, you could make your solution even faster by pre-computing all primes up to `sqrt(n2)`, and using them to test whether other numbers are prime or not.

Answer (score 0):

For starters 2 is a prime number. And every number is divisible by itself. So this condition

```
if(i%j==0)
```

will be always equal to `true` when `j` is equal to `i`.

The function can be written the following way

```
int isPrime( unsigned int x )
{
    int prime = ( x == 2 ) || ( x % 2 != 0 && x > 2 );

    for ( unsigned int i = 3; prime && i * i <= x; i += 2 )
    {
        prime = x % i != 0;
    }

    return prime;
}
```